Integral of absolute value of $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$
How to prove that:
$$\int_1^\infty \Big| \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \Big| dx = \infty$$
It's been asked when lower limit is $0$
I want to avoid proving it for lower limit $0$, how can it be done directly for $1$?
Thanks

$\int_0^1 |\frac {\sin x} x| dx \le 1 < \infty$ since $|\frac {\sin x} x| \le 1$. so if you had $\int_1^\infty |\frac {\sin x} x| dx < \infty$, you could just add $\int_0^1 |\frac {\sin x} x| dx < \infty$ to get that $\int_0^\infty |\frac {\sin x} x| dx < \infty$

I want to prove it directly for lower limit $1$

We can modified the linked answer above as follows: Since $[\pi, \infty) = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty [n\pi, (n + 1)\pi) \subseteq [1, \infty)$, and $\left\vert \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right\vert$ is nonnegative, we have
$$
    \int_1^{\infty} \left\vert \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \right\vert dx \ge \int_{\pi}^{\infty} \left\vert \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \right\vert dx = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n + 1)\pi} \left\vert \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \right\vert dx
$$
Proceed the same as the linked answer to prove the RHS is $\infty$ to finish.
